# How To Call A Function To Make A Graph Using HighCharts in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, highcharts

i'm starting to learn PHP, JavaScript, JQuery... 
I need to make a graph, and I'm going to use HighCharts. I have a form with 3 select and a button. When i push the button, I want to display the graph. The function to make the graph is on the examples, but I don't know if I need to put the function in another PHP file, or JavaScript file, how to call the function and how to pass parameters...
The code to make the graph is this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
    var chart;
    $(document).ready(function() {
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
           chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
            },
            subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Population (millions)',
                    align: 'high'
                },
                labels: {
                    overflow: 'justify'
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return ''+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +' millions';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                bar: {
                    dataLabels: {
                         enabled: true
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                layout: 'vertical',
                align: 'right',
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                x: -100,
                y: 100,
                floating: true,
                borderWidth: 1,
                backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
                shadow: true
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
               name: 'Year 1800',
                data: [107, 31, 635, 203, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 1900',
                data: [133, 156, 947, 408, 6]
            }, {
                name: 'Year 2008',
                data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
            }]
        });
    });
});
</script>
<script src="../../js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="../../js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you're not depending on any ajax calls to your server you don't need to involve PHP at all yet.  Once you need to communicate with a database or do other server-side processing, that'll be where you need PHP.

Just put that code into the body of an html file (eg index.html) and it should work fine.

Comment: If i just put that code, the graph will be displayed at first, but I need to take the options selected by the "select", to make the graph. So, i need to call that code when i push the button